# Express 4 js failed to lookup view in views directory

Tags: express, handlebars.js

Many similar questions on here with a similar issue but none of them have resolved my issue.

Using Express 4 with the error: "**Error: Failed to lookup view "test" in views directory "c:\Users\App\views\"
   at EventEmitter.render (c:\Users\App\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:579:17)**

Line 579 in the application.js says:

```
if (!view.path) {
  var dirs = Array.isArray(view.root) && view.root.length > 1
    ? 'directories "' + view.root.slice(0, -1).join('", "') + '" or "' + view.root[view.root.length - 1] + '"'
    : 'directory "' + view.root + '"'
  var err = new Error('Failed to lookup view "' + name + '" in views ' + dirs);
  err.view = view;
  return done(err);
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var express  = require('express'),
exphbs   = require('express-handlebars'),
path     = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
parser   = require('body-parser'),
ranges   = require('./models/ranges.js'),
app      = express();

app.use(parser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// View engine - handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'   }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
// Index page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('test');
});
```

Directory structure of App:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#extnamehandlebars), your Handlebars setup should look like this:

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Comment: Doh!  I was using the default view name for express if handlebars would have been used without the express-handlebars module.   Thanks!

Comment: They also have examples that reference the old way of using it in 3.0 i believe.  https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/examples/basic/server.js